# C# read text file lines multi thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to write a fast multi thread program using c# that read a file.

so the file must be split into some parts and each part process in different thread. for ex:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

must split to 4 lines like this:

```
Line1 => thread 1
Line2 => thread 2
Line3 => thread 3
Line4 = > thread 4
```

i used the `StreamReader.readLine()` but it cant read specify line.

Comment: its necessary to speedup the program so i want to read file in separate threads.

Comment: Why do you think a multi threading will help with this?

Comment: What makes you think it will be faster with several threads? I/O bound tasks are usually not good candidates for parallelization...

Comment: You won't see a performance increase. Your disk can only serve bits at a particular speed, and your computer is *not* faster than your disk. Basically, you seem to think that the bottleneck is your software, when it's most likely the Disk I/O.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're using fixed-length lines, this isn't possible.

Why? Because in order to determine where the "lines" split, you need to find the newline characters... which means you need to read the file first.

Now, if you simply want to perform some extra "processing" **after** you read in each line - that is possible and relatively straight-forward using a `ThreadPool`.

Comment: not the number of lines... the **length** of each line. Is that fixed?

Comment: If the **length** of each line is fixed, you can use a `FileStream` and set the position to the required offset. However, I really don't think this will help you - as the bottleneck is almost definitely disk speed... so more threads != faster reading from disk.

Answer (score 5):

You should *read the file* in a single thread - but then spawn the *processing* of each line to a different thread, e.g. by adding it to a producer/consumer queue.

Even if you *could* seek to a specific line in a text file (which in general you can't) you really don't want the disk thrashing around - that'll only slow things down. The fastest way to get the data off the disk is to read it sequentially. By all means defer *everything* about handling the line beyond "decoding the binary data to text" to other threads, but you really don't want the IO to be in multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK .NET doesn't support parallel stream reading. If you want to process every line you may use File.ReadAllLines. It returns an array of strings. Then use you can use PLINQ.

```
var result = File.ReadAllLine("path")
   .AsParallel()
   .Select(s => DoSthWithString(s))
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to speed up the actual reading because you're going to have tremendous locking issues keeping everything straight.

Since a text file is an unstructured file, ie. each line can be of different length, you have no choice but to read each line after the other, one by one.

Now, what you *can* do is *process* those lines on different threads, but the actual reading, keep that to one thread.

But, before you do that, are you sure you even have to do this? Is this a bottleneck? If not, fix the bottleneck first and see how far you get.

Answer (score 1):

Your StreamReader is connected to a stream class.  Using the stream class you can .Seek to a particular byte location.

Like others have said, this probably isn't a good idea, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the file before hand. Say the file is 1000 lines. Split it into 10 files of 100 lines. Have a thread process each file.